# Find the distribution of X (coin tosses)

Tags: probability

The problem is:

> Let $X$ be the number if coin tosses until heads is obtained. The probability of heads is $Y \in U(0,1)$. Find the distribution of $X$

So my thinking is that I have to use Law of total probability, since the chapter contains conditioning:

$$P(X)=\sum_y P(X|Y)\dot P(Y)$$

But I can not find the conditional distribution, so how do I proceed?

Comment: $Y$ is continuously distributed, so you'll need the appropriate statement of the law of total probability for that case. (The version you have applies to the discrete case.) For the conditional distribution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: Ok.
So if I use the right statement: $P(X)=\int P(X|Y=y)f_Y(y) dy$, then I still have the same problem. I have read the wikipediapage, but I still don´t know how to determine the conditional distribution.

Comment: The conditional distribution you want appears on the Wikipedia page. Remember that what you want to find is $\Pr(X=k \vert Y= y)$. That is, suppose that the probability of a head is $y$. What is the probability that I need to toss a coin $k$ times before seeing a head?

Comment: I´m losing my mind! I have read the Wikipedia page several times now, but I can´t see what distribution you are referring to. I guess it´s a Beta-distribution given the answer below, but then according to my book that distribution has two parameters and the one in the answer below only has $y$ as a parameter.

Comment: I think I got it, is $X=k|Y=y\sim Bin(k,y)$?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The binomial distribution counts the number of successes in a given number of trials. You want the number of trials for a given number of (well, actually, just one) successes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see where my reasoning went wrong... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional pmf of $X$ is
$$f_{X \mid Y}(k \mid y) =
 \operatorname P(X = k \mid Y = y) = (1 - y)^{k - 1} y, \\
k \in \mathbb N, 0 < y < 1.$$
To see where $(1 - y)^{k - 1} y$ comes from, just consider a coin that comes up heads with probability $y$ and find the probability of $T^{k-1}H$.

Now the (mixed) joint pdf with explicitly written out indicator functions for the $k$ and $y$ domains is
$$f_{X, Y}(k, y) = f_{X \mid Y}(k \mid y) f_Y(y) =
(1 - y)^{k - 1} y \,\mathbf 1_\mathbb N(k) \mathbf 1_{(0, 1)}(y).$$
Taking the marginal distribution, we obtain the pmf for $X$:
$$f_X(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X, Y}(k, y) dy =
\int_0^1 (1 - y)^{k - 1} y \,dy \,\mathbf 1_\mathbb N(k)  =
\frac 1 {k(k + 1)} \,\mathbf 1_\mathbb N(k)$$
(the Yule-Simon distribution).

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Easy to follow for a begginer like me.

Answer (score 0):

Note : I assume here that *each coin toss uses an independent uniformly distributed random variable Y1,..,Yk* to determine the probability of getting head. If the uniform variable realization $y=Y(\omega)$ is fixed and used for every coin tosses then my proof is false.

Let's call $C_Y$ the outcome of a coin toss with probability of tossing head equal to $Y \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$. $C_Y=1$ means we toss head. 
$$\mathbb P (X=k) = P (C_Y=0)^{k-1} P (C_Y=1) $$

Note that $C_Y|Y=y \sim \mathcal B(y)$, therefore:

$$\mathbb P (C_Y=1) = \mathbb E (C_Y) = \mathbb E(\mathbb E (C_Y|Y)) = \mathbb E(Y)  =  \int_{0}^1 y  \ dy = \frac 12  $$

Therefore,

$$\mathbb P (X=k) = (\frac 12) ^{k-1} (\frac 12) = \frac 1{2^k} $$

Comment: This is incorrect. $\mathbb P (X=k) = \mathbb E[\mathbb P(X=k \vert Y)] \neq \mathbb P(X = k \vert Y = \mathbb E(Y))$.

Comment: Thanks for reading what I did. I try to understand. You mean that my first equation is incorrect ?

Comment: Yes. You can’t treat the coin tosses as independent without conditioning on $Y$ first.

Comment: The way I see the problem is that each coin toss uses an independent uniformly distributed random variable $Y_1,..,Y_k$ to determine the probability of getting head. Do you think that all coin tosses are using the same $Y(\omega)=y$ as probability of getting heads?

Comment: If the problem correspond to the latter I understand why my first equation is wrong

Comment: I believe the problem corresponds to the latter interpretation. It seems unnatural to use a single random variable $Y$ to refer to the probability of heads when it changes every time you toss the coin... however, I suppose your interpretation isn’t unreasonable. It doesn’t seem the natural one to me, however.

Comment: Yes your understanding fits a Bayesian logic which is very likely to be the context of the problem. Anyway do you think my answer is right within the framework I described?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. However, you should probably make clear your interpretation of the question at the start of your answer, rather than here in the comments.

Comment: Done. Thank you